# How to prevent onload from running always?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a function I want to run when the homepage of a website is first loaded. However, I don't want that function to run if, instead of getting to the homepage by accessing it directly, I get there because I clicked on a link on the site that directs me there.
For this, I direct every link that gets you to the homepage to `home.html#loaded` instead of `home.html`. I also created the function below to be the one `onload` executes:

```
function onloadPreventer(fun) {
    if (window.location.hash != "#loaded") {
        //alert(window.location.hash);
        window.location = window.location + "#loaded";
        //alert(window.location.hash);
        fun;
    };
};
```

This function should only execute the function `fun` if there is no `#loaded` after `home.html`. However, it always executes `fun`.
However, the weird part is that it does not add `#loaded` once again:

When I first go to `home.html` (without hash) -- and if I comment out the `alert` statements -- it first gives me nothing, then gives me `#loaded` and then runs `fun`. All as it should.
If I go to `home` from another page, I'm already first loading `home.html#loaded`. The page alerts nothing, `onloadPreventer` does not add another `#loaded` at the end of the current location, **but `fun` runs anyway**.

The above function is called from inside the `<body>` tag, through an `onload` event:

```
<body onload="onloadPreventer(anotherFunction(arg))">
```

Unlike what the comments below suggest, `fun` *does* run. My problem is that even if the page has the hash `#loaded`, the rest of the code inside the `if` statement does not run, but `fun` still does.

What's wrong with this code?
And is there another way (possibly simpler) to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: is the parameter `fun` a function? if yes, is it calles anywhere else? 
when is the onloadPreventer called?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're asking for here; `1` Client opens homepage, `2` if _URI's hash_ not `#loaded`, go to `#loaded`, `3a` if we ended up at `#loaded` then end, `3b` if we didn't end up at `#loaded` then `fun()`?

Comment: Note that `fun;` doesn't call the function. You must have `fun()` somewhere else, or maybe it's an event handler.

Comment: @Oriol I know `fun;` does not call a function, unless I enter a function as a parameter for the `onloadPreventer` function.

Comment: @Homungus `fun` is a function, just called from inside `onloadPreventer`, which is loaded on `<body onload>`.

Comment: @JNat Even if you call `onloadPreventer` with a function, e.g. `onloadPreventer(function(){alert('a')})`, `fun` won't be called. It should be `fun()`.

Comment: Could you post some more code? E.g. how you connect the onload-event to the `onloadPreventer` and passing the parameter `fun`

Comment: @PaulS. I want the function `fun` to run *only* if there is no hash `#loaded`.

Comment: Basically, if I arrive at the page with an hash, I want `onloadPreventer` to do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are confused with functions:

```
function foo(){ /* ... */ } /* does NOT call foo */
function bar(){ /* ... */ } /* does NOT call bar */
foo;                        /* does NOT call foo */
foo(arg);         /* DOES call foo with arg as argument  */
foo(bar);         /* does NOT call bar, and DOES call foo with bar as argument */
foo(bar(arg));    /* DOES call bar with argument arg, and DOES call foo
                     with the returned value of bar as argument */
```

Then, you are calling a function if, and only if, you use parentheses.

(Alternatively, you can make browser to call functions for you, e.g. making them event handlers, or delayed functions with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. In those cases you don't use parentheses.)

In your case, you can use

```
function onloadPreventer(fun) {
    if (location.hash !== (location.hash = "#loaded")) {
        fun(); // DOES call fun
    }
}
```

But `fun` must be a function, not the returned value by a function:

```
<body onload="onloadPreventer(
     function(){anotherFunction(arg);} /* does NOT call anotherFunction */
)">
```

But better separate scripts from content:

```
function fun() {
    anotherFunction(arg);
}
document.body.onload = function onloadPreventer() {
    if (location.hash !== (location.hash = "#loaded")) {
        fun(); // DOES call fun
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I now get it. In your first code block, the last example explains where I went wrong. The code was executing the first function, with the returned value of the second one as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my tests:

I have two rudimentary pages:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var callWhenNoHash = function() {
    console.log('called');
};
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash != '#hash') {
        callWhenNoHash();
    }
};
</script></head>
<body><a href="test2.html">test2</a></body>
</html>
```

and:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<a href="test1.html#hash">test2</a>
</body></html>
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: This still runs `fun`, even if the page has the `#loaded` hash. So I still have the same problem. Also, any particular reason for calling `onload` here instead of from within `<body>`?

Comment: No particular reason, I just guessed what you were doin. Could you provide a sample page with your problem? I'm really not getting the issue here.

Comment: Could this be a browser problem? 'Cause that code does nothing for me? I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm:

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/refah/1)

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var load = "#loaded";
  if (window.location.hash != load) {
    window.location = window.location + load;
    document.write(load);
  };
})
```

Your problem is in here: `onload="onloadPreventer(anotherFunction(arg))`

The "anotherFunction" is running because of the () after it.

You can use `onload="onloadPreventer(anotherFunction)` or use **[event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)** since we are no longer in the dark ages!